Could not set interface wlxffffffffffff flags (UP): Cannot assign requested address
I have a Realtek RTL8188EUS USB Wi-Fi dongle. When I plug it in to a computer running Ubuntu 24.04, the dongle appears in the network applet, but it doesn't list any Wi-Fi networks. sudo journalctl -a says:
kernel: usb 3-5.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 3-5.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8179, bcdDevice= 0.00
kernel: usb 3-5.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 3-5.4: Product: 802.11n NIC
kernel: usb 3-5.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
kernel: usb 3-5.4: SerialNumber: 00E04C8188FF
mtp-probe[5487]: checking bus 3, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.4"
mtp-probe[5487]: bus: 3, device: 8 was not an MTP device
kernel: usb 3-5.4: RTL8188EU rev D (TSMC) romver 0, 1T1R, TX queues 2, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
kernel: usb 3-5.4: RTL8188EU MAC: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
kernel: usb 3-5.4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin
kernel: usb 3-5.4: Firmware revision 28.0 (signature 0x88e1)
kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
NetworkManager[2198]: <info>  [1732831747.3254] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
mtp-probe[5502]: checking bus 3, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.4"
mtp-probe[5502]: bus: 3, device: 8 was not an MTP device
systemd[1]: Starting systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
kernel: rtl8xxxu 3-5.4:1.0 wlxffffffffffff: renamed from wlan0
systemd[1]: Started systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
NetworkManager[2198]: <info>  [1732831747.3591] rfkill2: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5.4/3-5.4:1.0/ieee80211/phy1/rfkill2) (driver rtl8xxxu)
NetworkManager[2198]: <info>  [1732831747.3644] device (wlan0): interface index 4 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlxffffffffffff'
NetworkManager[2198]: <info>  [1732831747.3859] device (wlxffffffffffff): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
NetworkManager[2198]: <warn>  [1732831747.3874] platform-linux: do-change-link[4]: failure 99 (Cannot assign requested address)
wpa_supplicant[2201]: Could not set interface wlxffffffffffff flags (UP): Cannot assign requested address
wpa_supplicant[2201]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlxffffffffffff' UP
wpa_supplicant[2201]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlxffffffffffff disabled_11b_rates=0
wpa_supplicant[2201]: Could not set interface wlxffffffffffff flags (UP): Cannot assign requested address
wpa_supplicant[2201]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlxffffffffffff' UP
wpa_supplicant[2201]: wlxffffffffffff: Failed to initialize driver interface
wpa_supplicant[2201]: wlxffffffffffff: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
NetworkManager[2198]: <error> [1732831747.3972] device (wlxffffffffffff): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.

How can I get the dongle to work?

The dongle's MAC address is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, which is obviously invalid. (Maybe the technician forgot to program a MAC address at the factory?) You can make it work anyway if you edit the following section in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

Change it to:
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=yes
wifi.cloned-mac-address=random

Then run sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager to make the new settings take effect. With those settings, NetworkManager will set the dongle's MAC address to a random but valid value, and it will work normally. See this blog post for more information.

MAC randomization was disabled because it made USB wifi devices unusable in Ubuntu 17.04/17.10

Do you know which USB Wi-Fi dongles randomization breaks? Mine definitely needs it.

I don't know of one that worked after the change in 17.04/17.10.  Now it doesn't seem to affect my dongle that is the same as the OP.  I don't see the RTL8188EU MAC: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff either with or without MAC randomization
